# Multi-option cookie compliance

Tags: magento2, cookie

When a user visits my Magento 2 site for the first time, I want to display a multi-option cookie banner where I have a list of all non-essential cookies split into groups, allowing them to allow or deny various groups of cookies.

I'd be interested to know how I can how can remove any unauthorised cookies ensuring that the cookies that were denied are not created again for the duration of the session. Obviously if they are denied by the user, the website must still provide a basic level of functionality without causing errors.

I understand this is a complex task but if somebody could point me in the right direction this would be helpful. I have found several existing commercial extensions on the market that claim to help with cookie compliance. Does anyone know if there any in existence that will come close to accomplishing this task.

Thank you

David